# Scala subtype parameter

Tags: scala

I created a class `Project` extending a `Model`:

```
abstract class Model
case class Project(...) extends Model
```

and an object `Table` extending `Base`:

```
abstract class Base {
    val tableForm: Form[Model]
}

object Table extends Base {
    val tableForm: Form[Project] = (...)
}
```

Why is it that it won't compile and how can I fix it? (*"overriding method/value tableForm in class Base of type => Form[Model]"*)

I just wanted to force all subclasses of `Base` to have a `tableForm` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Form[Project]` is not a subclass of `Form[Model]`. So the compiler complains about incompatible type in overriding value.

`Form[T]` is invariant. You can read the [variance doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html)

To fix this, you can add a type parameter to `Base`.

```
abstract class Base[M <: Model] {
  val tableForm: Test[M]
}

object Table extends Base[Project] {
  val tableForm: Test[Project] = ???
}
```

Comment: Great! I knew there was a [T <: Model] somewhere, but I couldn't figure where to place it. And now I can use it as a type with `val b: Base[_ <: Model]`, if any other newbie like me wonders.

Comment: You can also define an abstract type `type T <: Model`. Then you don't need the `[_ <: Model]` part.